# String reverse Built-in ES6

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, reverse, ecmascript-2016

- [10 implementations](http://eddmann.com/posts/ten-ways-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript/) of **String#reverse**  have been profiled according to each browser.
- Those implementations have been explained since 2011.
- When ES6 came , there are many code become more **elegant** & **performance**  .
- Concerning **String** reversing , I am wondered, if ES6 supports it .
- Anyway, i end up with this syntax :

  ```
  reverse=(str)=>[...str].reverse().join('');
  ```

## My question is :

Does ES6/ES7 has built-in API more **elegant** & **brief** & **performance** for that ?

Comment: You question fails to define some terms, and so is not a question yet. What is "elegant" (other than something every person on SO has their own opinion on, thus being off-topic)? What is "brief" (lines of code to use? number of characters to use? amount of syntax necessary?)? As for performance: you can easily test that one yourself. And most importantly: what matters is why you're reversing those strings. I can guarantee you that if the perf or terseness of the code *really* matters, whatever algorithm you're writing does not need reversing strings at all, it needs better implementation.

Comment: At least you can post your own `[...str].reverse().join('')` answer to give some sense to the question. Obviously, iterables are the only new ES6 things that are usable in the context.

Comment: I really don't know why you received negative on this (at least, I've upvoted you). I just had the same question as you. And, finally, thanks for sharing your temporary solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Reference: [String object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) in the Mozilla Developer Network does not have any `reverse()` method.